# "Attempting to reduce pending async count below zero." error in angular-dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Since i'm in angularDart v1 i getting this error

> Attempting to reduce pending async count below zero.

```
STACKTRACE:
#0      PendingAsync.increaseCount (package:angular/core/pending_async.dart:48:7)
#1      PendingAsync.decreaseCount (package:angular/core/pending_async.dart:59:54)
#2      RootScope.RootScope.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/scope.dart:769:34)
#3      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:892)
#4      _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:499)
#5      VmTurnZone._finishTurn (package:angular/core/zone.dart:168:21)
#6      VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:111:43)
#7      _onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:17)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:801)
#9      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:709)
#10     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:735)
```

I don't really where it comes from, if someone can help me about this.

I can't really past the code because it's too heavy and a little private sorry. I hope someone will be able to help me